# Foundation 6 Tabs addressing multiple tabs-content blocks

Tags: tabs, zurb-foundation

I want to use one tab navigation to control 2 tab-content blocks using foundation 6. At the moment my first tab-content blocks works as it should the second does not. When I click the second tab it adds the contents of the second tab to the bottom of the first in the second tab-content container and doesn't remove it.

```
        <div class="cell  medium-6  text-padding">

            <ul class="tabs"  data-tabs id="floorplan">
                <li class="tabs-title  is-active"><a href="#ground" aria-selected="true">Ground Floor</a></li>
                <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#first">First floor</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tabs-content"  data-tabs-content="floorplan">
                <div class="tabs-panel  is-active" id="ground">
                   <p>Tab 1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="tabs-panel" id="first">
                    <p>Tab 2</p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="cell  medium-6">
            <div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="floorplan">
                <div class="tabs-panel  is-active" id="ground">
                   <p>Tab 1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="tabs-panel" id="first">
                    <p>Tab 2</p> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Tab Content uses id's so you can't get away with using two sets of tab content with the same id's.

If you have to control the tabs from one set of buttons, then you might switch to data-attributes and use the custom methods to trigger a tab change. https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/tabs.html#js-functions